# Problema ao adicionar produtos ao carrinho

Tags: php, html5

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'])){
    $_SESSION['itens'] = array();
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id= $_POST['id'];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$id])){
        $_SESSION['itens'][$id] = 1;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['itens'][$id] += 1;
    }
}



$consulta = "SELECT * FROM informaoces WHERE id='$id'";
$con = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta);
?>
```

Nome do produto
            preço
            quantidade

Qual o problema desse código,
Quando vou adicionar outros produto ao carrinho, eles não ficar adicionados na mesma tabela, agora se ficar adicionando o mesmo produtos mais de uma vez, aumenta a quantidade, agora se adicionar outro produto diferentes; não vai pra mesma tabela

Comment: Não entendi. você quer obter a informação de um produto atráves de uma requisição ? Qual o objetivo de $_POST já que os itens estão em $_SESSIONS ?

Comment: Não está faltando `session_start();` nesse código não?

Comment: esse seu código faz isso http://kithomepage.com/sos/carrinho.php cria um array sendo as chaves  os ids e aos valores vai somando +1 ao valor da  chave  já criada. Cuidado que está criando também se enviar campo nulo

Comment: A session_start() tem

Comment: Atila silva esse método POST é para enviar o id de uma página para outra